# "No matching route for request" message when updating task using Asana API

Tags: asana

I am trying to update a task in Asana using the Asana API. I can create the task successfully but when I update it I get the message "No matching route for request".

I am doing an PUT to the URL https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/2768594478959 with the body containing:

```
{"data":{"id":2768594478959,"name":"Test 5","notes":"Test 5 Notes"}}
```

My content type is  set to `application/json`.

If I copy the https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/2768594478959 URL to the browser it does return the task.

Does anyone have any idea why I may be getting this error?

Thanks,

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this call from within NetSuite using its proprietary HTTP request function, and it turns out that it was doing a POST even though I was telling it to do a PUT.

I used http://httpbin.org to figure this out.

Regards,
Wayne